# height in percentage vs padding-bottom in percentage

Tags: html, css

recently I found an responsive website which changes the image contents in different size of screen. When the screen size is big like desktop computer, the content of the div is like(there is no other text content, just a div filled with an image using background-image):

```
#div {
    background-image: url('images/pc-content01.jpg');
    background: no-repeat center center;
    height: 1129px;
}
```

When the screen size gets smaller, the css style changes like:

```
#div {
    background-image: url('images/pc-content01.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 95.5%;
}
```

And the background image will be swap to another image when the screen size is as small as moblie devices.

And my question is, how the percentage of padding-bottom is calculated, why percentage in height is not working but percentage on padding-bottom works?
(I understand why percentage on height is not working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In padding percentages refer to the width of the containing block. In this case is used to maintain the aspect ratio (the image one) when the width changes. It is a trick often used in responsive design. [A box with an intrinsic ratio](https://alistapart.com/d/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/example2.html). Percentage in height works differently

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block...

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height), so is not suitable for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

When using a percentage value for paddings, it always refers to the *width* of the element. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding#Values). So in this case the `padding-bottom` of `#div` would be 95.5% of its width. When setting percentage value for `height` it calculates it by using the height of the containing block. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height#Values)

Answer (score 2):

***Height in percentage***

Height using percentage only works if we give height using percentage to the `body and html` of the page, it will not work otherwise.

Like this-

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
   background:black;
}

body>div{
 height:50%;
 background:gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div>HI</div>
</body>
```

***Padding-bottom in percentage***

But in the case of percentage on padding-bottom, it works irrespective to the `body or HTML`. It only checks the `width of the containing element`.

Like this -

```css
html, body{
   background:black;
}

div{
 background:gray;
 padding-bottom:20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>HI</div>
</body>
```